# Vertically arranged multiple monitors: some apps won't let me drag them "above" the menu bar

Tags: xcode, display

I'm working on a MacBook Pro, with my external monitor arranged on a higher shelf, and "arranged" within my display preferences as being "above" my MBP display.  I use the larger monitor when I'm coding, using the terminal, etc., and the MBP display for browsing, IM, and other things.

My problem is this: some apps won't let me drag them to beyond the menu bar on the MBP display.  If I arrange the displays in a horizontal configuration, or with the MBP display "above" the external monitor, I can drag the windows wherever I want.  An example of some apps that do this are Sublime Text 2 and XCode.

Is there some trick to getting this to work that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to choose which monitor will have the menubar in the 'Displays' section of System Preferences.

Go to System Preferences, click 'Displays', and choose the 'Orientation' tab. If you click and hold on the small white rectangle signifying the menu bar, you can move it between screens and move it to the top most display.